# Zip two lists of different lengths and repeat the items from the shorter list

Tags: python

I'm trying to *zip* two lists of different lengths in Python so the items in the the second one are *zipped* iteratively over the elements in the first one.

I have tried using `itertools.product` without much luck. Is it possible to achieve this with some module in the standard library?

E.g

```
import itertools
a = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
b = [1, 2, 3]
list(itertools.product(a, b))
```

Result:

```
 [('a', 1),
 ('a', 2),
 ('a', 3),
 ('b', 1),
 ('b', 2),
 ('b', 3),
 ('c', 1),
 ('c', 2),
 ('c', 3)
 [...],
```

**Desired result:**

```
 [('a', 1),
 ('b', 2),
 ('c', 3),
 ('d', 1),
 ('e', 2),
 ('f', 3)]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `itertools.cycle` to infinitely repeat you smaller list

```
zip(a, itertools.cycle(b))
```